# Considering math or computer science

Tags: soft-question, computer-science, education

Let me start by saying I graduated High School in 2002 and have worked as a technician, a systems administrator, and a part time web developer up till now.

I have started taking courses at community college for my general requirements, and I am planning which major I should pursue.  I have always had a passion for mathematics since a young age, but never pursued it, and currently I would say my level of math is at a algebra level.  My understanding for computers and programming is much greater than mathematics.

Should I consider taking Math as my major or go with Computer Science?  I do not want to do a double major, since I have no real plans for staying in College for that long.  My goal is to receive a degree, gain educational experience, and take my career to the next level.  I plan on working as a programmer professionally.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To be honest, this is a personal question that likely can not and should not be answered by a group of strangers. With that said, programming jobs are often filled by both CS and math students, though CS students generally start at a higher position due to experience. Those with strong math backgrounds typically have great intuition on how to approach problems, but a lack of experience in things like formal software engineering practices can limit your options. From my experience as a double major in math and CS, the job opportunities for CS graduates are everywhere. My math background has helped me within the job, but is seemingly neglected in the application/interview process. Ultimately the decision should be made based on your existing background and exactly what you want to accomplish in school (gain educational experience is a little too vague).